# Sybase: convert Int to Decimal

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a column that holds a 7 length integer which is used for a percentage field, with 4 decimal places, i.e. 1234657 = 123.4567%, 100000 = 100.0000%.

I would like to return the `discountp` field as a percentage in the format ###.####

I have tried the following but none return it

```
str(discountp, 7,4)
```

> Returns 100000

```
Cast(convert(nvarchar, discountp) as decimal(7,4)),
```

> Arithmetic overflow during explicit conversion of VARCHAR value '1000000' to a DECIMAL field

```
convert(decimal(4),cast(discountp as Int)),
```

> Arithmetic overflow during explicit conversion of INT value '1000000' to a DECIMAL field

```
cast(discountp as decimal(7,4))
```

> Arithmetic overflow during explicit conversion of INT NULL value '1000000' to a DECIMAL field

Comment: Does `str(cast(discountp as decimal)/1000, 7, 4)` work?

Comment: It's very close! That returns me `1000.00`

Comment: Sorry, should have been 10000. Could you show us where `discountp` is declared? I'm not sure that the idea of a "7-length integer" makes sense - it sounds like a string.

Comment: Sorry, I was getting myself mixed up. It is an int column on the table, I only mentioned the 7 as every int in that table is that same format of 7 digits.